# Error when trying to import Keras pad_sequences and eli5

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I get an error every time I try to import either pad_sequences from Keras or eli5. This is happening in two different Jupyter Notebooks. This is the first piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

The error I get is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/b7/t53bdffs3h74zjqsljqdq6l00000gn/T/ipykernel_14200/2583752154.py in <module>
      8 import pandas as pd
      9 import tensorflow as tf
---> 10 from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
     11 
     12 tf.__version__

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>
     23 
     24 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
---> 25 from keras import models
     26 
     27 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/models.py in <module>
     18 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
     19 from keras import backend
---> 20 from keras import metrics as metrics_module
     21 from keras import optimizer_v1
     22 from keras.engine import functional

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/metrics.py in <module>
     25 
     26 import numpy as np
---> 27 from keras import activations
     28 from keras import backend
     29 from keras.engine import base_layer

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/activations.py in <module>
     18 
     19 from keras import backend
---> 20 from keras.layers import advanced_activations
     21 from keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
     22 from keras.utils.generic_utils import serialize_keras_object

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py in <module>
     22 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
     23 # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
---> 24 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     25 from keras.engine.input_layer import InputLayer
     26 from keras.engine.input_spec import InputSpec

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py in <module>
     19 from keras import backend
     20 from keras.distribute import distributed_training_utils
---> 21 from keras.engine import base_layer
     22 from keras.engine import keras_tensor
     23 from keras.engine import node as node_module

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in <module>
     39 from keras.engine import node as node_module
     40 from keras.mixed_precision import autocast_variable
---> 41 from keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale_optimizer
     42 from keras.mixed_precision import policy
     43 from keras.saving.saved_model import layer_serialization

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/mixed_precision/loss_scale_optimizer.py in <module>
   1178 
   1179 # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 1180 mixed_precision._register_wrapper_optimizer_cls(optimizer_v2.OptimizerV2,
   1181                                                 LossScaleOptimizerV1)
   1182 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.experimental.mixed_precision' has no attribute '_register_wrapper_optimizer_cls'
```

This is the second piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Data visualisation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)
sns.set(font_scale=1)
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
#Modeling
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, cross_val_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn_crfsuite import CRF, scorers, metrics
from sklearn_crfsuite.metrics import flat_classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV, train_test_split
import scipy.stats
import eli5
```

And the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/b7/t53bdffs3h74zjqsljqdq6l00000gn/T/ipykernel_14209/2789971785.py in <module>
     20 from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV, train_test_split
     21 import scipy.stats
---> 22 import eli5

~/Dropbox/Dox/Sogeti/PGGM/do_mimir/do_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eli5/__init__.py in <module>
     91 
     92 try:
---> 93     from .keras import (
     94         explain_prediction_keras
     95     )

~/Dropbox/Dox/Sogeti/PGGM/do_mimir/do_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eli5/keras/__init__.py in <module>
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
      2 
----> 3 from .explain_prediction import explain_prediction_keras
      4 from .gradcam import gradcam, gradcam_backend

~/Dropbox/Dox/Sogeti/PGGM/do_mimir/do_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eli5/keras/explain_prediction.py in <module>
      6 
      7 import numpy as np
----> 8 import keras
      9 import keras.backend as K
     10 from keras.models import Model

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>
     23 
     24 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
---> 25 from keras import models
     26 
     27 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/models.py in <module>
     18 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
     19 from keras import backend
---> 20 from keras import metrics as metrics_module
     21 from keras import optimizer_v1
     22 from keras.engine import functional

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/metrics.py in <module>
     25 
     26 import numpy as np
---> 27 from keras import activations
     28 from keras import backend
     29 from keras.engine import base_layer

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/activations.py in <module>
     18 
     19 from keras import backend
---> 20 from keras.layers import advanced_activations
     21 from keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
     22 from keras.utils.generic_utils import serialize_keras_object

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py in <module>
     22 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
     23 # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
---> 24 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     25 from keras.engine.input_layer import InputLayer
     26 from keras.engine.input_spec import InputSpec

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py in <module>
     19 from keras import backend
     20 from keras.distribute import distributed_training_utils
---> 21 from keras.engine import base_layer
     22 from keras.engine import keras_tensor
     23 from keras.engine import node as node_module

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in <module>
     39 from keras.engine import node as node_module
     40 from keras.mixed_precision import autocast_variable
---> 41 from keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale_optimizer
     42 from keras.mixed_precision import policy
     43 from keras.saving.saved_model import layer_serialization

~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/mixed_precision/loss_scale_optimizer.py in <module>
   1178 
   1179 # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 1180 mixed_precision._register_wrapper_optimizer_cls(optimizer_v2.OptimizerV2,
   1181                                                 LossScaleOptimizerV1)
   1182 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.experimental.mixed_precision' has no attribute '_register_wrapper_optimizer_cls'
```

I have tensorflow 2.6.0, keras 2.6.0 and Python 3.9.6. I'm working in a local venv on Mac Big Sur, version 11.5.1. Can anyone help? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi! Did you check the same code  with Python 3.7-3.8 yet?